# A closed form (or tight upper bound) for $\sum_{j=0}^{2m} (-1)^j (m-j)^{2m+2k} \binom{2m}{j}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, upper-bounds

I'm seeking a closed-form expression to the sum
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{2m} (-1)^j (m-j)^{2m+2k} \binom{2m}{j} $$
where for positive integers $m$ and $k$,  we know $m \gg k$. Loosely, $k \sim \log(m)$.

When $k=0$, this sum is equivalent to $(2m)!$. Is there a general strategy for attempting to simplify such sums, when their terms differ so simply (a factor $(m-j)^{2k}$) from those of a known sum?

If a closed-form is not possible, I am also interested in an upper bound tighter than what Stirling's approximation could produce (for example). All ideas welcome!

Comment: @PeterTaylor yep! Corrected

Comment: As to approximations, since the sum is a 2m-th discrete difference, it may be approximated by a 2m-th derivative.

Comment: @PietroMajer I found (via the OEIS! hehe) that when $k=0$, the sum equals $|\text{arccot}^{(2m+1)}(0)|$, but I'm not sure how to proceed for finite $k$. Any ideas?

Comment: I wrote a first bound via MVT, but sure one can do better...

Comment: Dividing these numbers by $(2m)!$ gives the central factorial numbers of the second kind, https://oeis.org/A036969 and https://oeis.org/A008957.

Answer (score 4):

For another approach, an alternative expression for your sum
$$S_k(m):=\sum_{j=0}^{2m}(-1)^j\binom{2m}j (m-j)^{2m+2k}$$
goes as follows.

(1) As you already noted, $S_0(m)=(2m)!$

(2) For $k\geq1$, the ratio $T_k(m):=\frac{S_k(m)}{S_0(m)}$ takes the form of sums of squares:
$$T_k(m)=\sum_{1\leq i_1\leq i_2\leq\cdots\leq i_k\leq m}(i_1i_2\cdots i_k)^2.$$

Although we don't have a "closed form" for the last sum, we can say that
$$T_k(m)=\binom{2m+2k}{2k+1}P_{k-1}(m) \qquad \text{or} \qquad
S_k(m)=\frac{(2m)\,(2m+2k)!}{(2k+1)!}\,P_{k-1}(m)$$
for some polynomial $P_{k-1}(m)$ in $m$ of degree $k-1$.

Comment: Polynomial $P_{k-1}(m)$ expliciltly expresses in terms of Bell polynomials as shown in my answer.

Comment: That is cool, Max.

Answer (score 3):

A first (rough) bound: the usual comparison between discrete difference & derivative of a $C^\infty$ function $u(x)$, given by iterated application of the Mean Value Theorem, gives
$\sum_{j=0}^{2m}(-1)^j{2m\choose j}u(m-j)=u^{(2m)}(\xi)$ for some $|\xi|<m$. Here $u(x):=x^{2m+2k}$ so $$0\le \sum_{j=0}^{2m}(-1)^j{2m\choose j}(m-j)^{2m+2k}=\frac{(2m+2k)!}{(2k)!}\xi^{2k}\le\frac{(2m+2k)!}{(2k)!}m^{2k} $$ (for $k=0$ we find the exact value $(2m)!$ as it has to be).

*(edit)* In fact, if in the above computation we use the FTC, $u(1/2)-u(-1/2)=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}u'(t)dt$, instead of the bound by MVT, we get an exact value via $2m$-iterated integrals
$\sum_{j=0}^{2m}(-1)^j{2m\choose j}u(m-j)=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\dots \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}u^{(2m)}(\sum_{i=1}^{2m}t_i)dt_1\dots dt_{2m}$;
here
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{2m}(-1)^j{2m\choose j}(m-j)^{2m+2k}=\frac{(2m+2k)!}{(2k)!}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\dots \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \Big(\sum_{i=1}^{2m}t_i\Big)^{2k}dt_1\dots dt_{2m}.$$

Comment: That's a great start! Indeed very loose; for $m = 10^4$ and $k = \lfloor \log(m)\rfloor = 9$, the bound is a factor $3 \times 10^{35}$ larger :(

Comment: :D ehm well still there are much more atoms in the universe -- here is a tentative exact formula

Comment: (To estimate the integral for $m\to\infty$ I guess one should see $t_1,t_2,\dots $ as independent random variables uniformly distributed on $[-1/2,1/2]$ and use some LLN)

Comment: I think it's the CLT rather than the LLN that one should use. This gives the rough estimate $\frac{(2m+2k)!}{k!}\times\left(\frac{m}{12}\right)^k$. To prove it rigorously, I would use Cauchy's formula in order to take the $2k$-th derivative of the characteristic function, since $k$ seems to vary with $m$.

Comment: With astonishment, I report you have obtained our original expression! :)

Comment: If you look for asymptotics, from the integral it should be easier..

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_k(m)$ denotes the sum in question. It can be expressed as $(2m+2k)!$ times the coefficient of $x^{2k}$ in
$$\mathrm{sinhc}(x/2)^{2m},$$
where $\mathrm{sinhc}$ is the [hyperbolic sinc](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SinhcFunction.html) function.

Then [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) gives the following expression in terms of Bell polynomials:
$$S_k(m) = \frac{(2m+2k)!}{(2k)!} \sum_{i=0}^{2k} (2m)_i B_{2k,i}(0,\frac1{3\cdot 2^2},0,\frac1{5\cdot 2^4},0,\frac1{7\cdot 2^6},\dots).$$
Note that the last sum has just $2k$ summands.

It can further be expressed explicitly as the sum over the partitions of $k$:
$$S_k(m) = (2m+2k)! \sum_{\lambda\, \vdash \, k} \frac{(2m)_{\ell(\lambda)}}{4^{\ell(\lambda)}} \prod_{j=1}^{k} \frac1{(2j+1)!^{\lambda^j}(\lambda^j)!},$$
where $\ell(\lambda)$ is the length and $\lambda^j$ is the multiplicity of $j$ in the partition $\lambda$.